# Which communications security options MongoDB provides?

Tags: mongodb, ssl

After reviewing several MongoDB official documents (see list at the bottom) I understand that MongoDB security in communications (as in community version 4.2) works as follows:

- For **internal communication authentication** (i.e. between the members of a replica set or between `mongos` and the replica sets which implement the different shards) there are two mechanisms available:

  - shared keyfile (`--keyFile`)
  - x.509 certificates
- For **internal communication encryption**, SSL/TLS is the only possibility. In other words, shared keyfile (`--keyFile`) provides only authentication, but if you want encryption you need to use SSL/TLS alternative. Using SSL/TLS requires to use x.509 certificates also (so, we can say that encryption also provides authentication)
- For **client to MongoDB communications** (either standalone, replica set or `mongos` in a shard cluster):

  - there isn't keyfile option
  - the only way to secure communication (which provides both authentication and encryption) is SSL/TLS with x.509 certificates

I'd like just to confirm my understanding, as the documentation I have browsed is a little "disperse" and I'm not sure if I have got the point. Any feedback, comment, extra info or documentation pointers is really welcome!

**PD:** the statement which I'm most unsure is this one: "*shared keyfile (`--keyFile`) provides only authentication, but if you want encryption you need to use SSL/TLS alternative*"

References checked:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication

Answer (score 1):

For client to MongoDB communications (either standalone, replica set or mongos in a shard cluster) there are several authentication methods:

- No authentication
- Internal authentication with username/password
- Kerberos Authentication
- LDAP Proxy Authentication
- LDAP Authentication

Note, you can always connect to MongoDB database, even without an account. However, you are not permitted to execute any command unless you are authenticated.